# Combining Result Sets that Use Unions

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have queries that use unions and I want to combine the queries into one result set.  Here is the sample query.  It returns two results sets.  I want to combine them into one.  Thanks!

QUERY 1

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Have you taken an interest/vocational assessment - Pre'
  FROM YESSCAYouth
WHERE Assess2Pre1 = 1
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM YESSCAYouth
 WHERE Assess2Pre1 = 2
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM YESSCAYouth
 WHERE Assess2Pre1 = 3
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM YESSCAYouth
 WHERE Assess2Pre1 = 1 or Assess2Pre1 = 2 or Assess2Pre1 = 3
   AND Assess2PreDate BETWEEN CAST('01/01/2012' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('12/31/2012' AS DATETIME)
```

QUERY 2

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Have you taken an interest/vocational assessment - Post'
  FROM YESSCAYouth
 WHERE Assess2Post1 = 1
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM YESSCAYouth
 WHERE Assess2Post1 = 2
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM YESSCAYouth
 WHERE Assess2Post1 = 3
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM YESSCAYouth
 WHERE Assess2Post1 = 1 or Assess2Post1 = 2 or Assess2Post1 = 3
   AND Assess2PostDate BETWEEN CAST('01/01/2012' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('12/31/2012' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: What is the problem to use `UNION` one more time?

Comment: What does it mean to "combine" them. Can't you just use another UNION?

Comment: I hope you're aware that there's no guarantee on the order in which results are returned from the above queries? Such that, given your query, there's no way to distinguish which of the rows represents `COUNT(*)...WHERE Assess2Pre1=2` and which one is `COUNT(*)...WHERE Assess2Pre1=3`...

Comment: Also shouldn't be using UNION ... If there are two queries where the count is 3, the UNION will eliminate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 1 as g, 'Have you taken an interest/vocational assessment - Pre' as x

UNION ALL 

SELECT 2 as g, cast(COUNT (1) as varchar) as x --as 'Have you taken an interest/vocational assessment - Pre'
FROM YESSCAYouth 
WHERE Assess2Pre1 = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 3 as g, cast(COUNT (1) as varchar) as x FROM YESSCAYouth
WHERE Assess2Pre1 = 2

UNION ALL

SELECT 4 as g, cast(COUNT (1) as varchar) as x FROM YESSCAYouth
WHERE Assess2Pre1 = 3

UNION ALL

SELECT 5 as g, cast(COUNT (1) as varchar) as x FROM YESSCAYouth
WHERE Assess2Pre1 = 1 or Assess2Pre1 = 2 or Assess2Pre1 = 3
AND
Assess2PreDate 
BETWEEN CAST('01/01/2012' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('12/31/2012' AS DATETIME)

UNION ALL
--QUERY 2 ****************************************

SELECT
6 as g, 'Have you taken an interest/vocational assessment - Post'

UNION
ALL 

SELECT
7 as g,cast(COUNT (1) as varchar) as x --as 'Have you taken an interest/vocational assessment - Post'
FROM
YESSCAYouth
WHERE
Assess2Post1 = 1

UNION
ALL

SELECT
8 as g, cast(COUNT (1) as varchar) as x FROM YESSCAYouth
WHERE
Assess2Post1 = 2

UNION
ALL

SELECT
9 as g, cast(COUNT (1) as varchar) as x FROM YESSCAYouth
WHERE
Assess2Post1 = 3

UNION
ALL

SELECT
10 as g, cast(COUNT (1) as varchar) as x FROM YESSCAYouth
WHERE
Assess2Post1 = 1 or Assess2Post1 = 2 or Assess2Post1 = 3
AND
Assess2PreDate 
BETWEEN CAST('01/01/2012' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('12/31/2012' AS DATETIME)
ORDER
BY g
```

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you want something like this:

```
select
   COALESCE(a1.Level,a2.Level) as Level,
   COALESCE(a1.Cnt,0) as 'Have you taken an interest/vocational assessment - Pre',
   COALESCE(a2.Cnt,0) as 'Have you taken an interest/vocational assessment - Post'
from
    (select Assess2Pre1,COUNT(*) from YESSCAYouth where Assess2Pre1 in (1,2,3) group by Assess2Pre1)
        a1(Level,Cnt)
            full outer join
    (select Assess2Post1,COUNT(*) from YESSCAYouth where Assess2Post1 in (1,2,3) group by Assess2Post1)
        a2(Level,Cnt)
            on
                a1.Level = a2.Level         
union all
select
    4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Assess2Pre1 in (1,2,3) and Assess2PreDate between '20120101' and '20121231' THEN 1 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN Assess2Post1 in (1,2,3) and Assess2PostDate between '20120101' and '20121231' THEN 1 END)
from YESSCAYouth
```

In the above, I've matched up the second and third columns so that they represent the comparable results from the two different states. I have then introduced a union to pull in the date based query.

If this *isn't* what you're looking for, please add some sample data and expected results to your question. (I'd note that my above query will be different from yours if the pre and post counts are both 0 for one of the "levels").

---

Other notes: `in()` is a real space saver, and is entirely equivalent to `column = value1 or column = value2...`. And `mm/dd/yyyy` isn't a safe format to use to convert to dates without using `CONVERT()` and specifying an explicit format. `yyyymmdd`, on the other hand, will always convert correctly.

Finally, there's a bit of a design smell around columns with names that include numbers - it suggests that there might be other identical columns with the same name but a different number - when usually, the right way to model this would be to introduce a column to hold that number, and store the data as multiple rows.

Comment: Close but I am looking to return the following results:
Have you taken an interest/vocational assessment - Pre
0
17
47
64
Have you taken an interest/vocational assessment - Post
0
15
34
49

Comment: @Lakeshore - a column in a result set has *one* name (and one type). You can't "rename" the column part way through - hence why I've put the results in two columns.

Answer (score 0):

you would just simply union the two query's; Wrap brackets around your query one and query two and put a union clause in between that'll give you a combined resultset.

(Query 1)

Union

(Query 2)

EDIT:  If you have differnt column names, you could try put it into a temp table and do a union on it; try run this in SQL Management Studio, it'll give you an idea;

```
select 'tt' as t, 'tete' as tt, 'tets' as ttt
into #test

select 'tt' as tre, 'tete' as tt, 'tets' as ttt
into #testt

select * from #test 
union 
select * from #testt

drop table #test
drop table #testt
```

Comment: That did not work.  I the first result set just like it is now added to the second result set.  UNION ALL combines the two along with the calculations...

Comment: I see, For a union to work all columns have to be the same; your first column is differnt bewtween the two "Have you taken an interest/vocational assessment - Pre" and "post"